# Laravel 5.6 server side exceptions return response in json instead of html

Tags: json, ajax, exception, response, laravel-5.6

So, I've noticed that as of the last version 5.6 Laravel returns the server side exceptions in a json format instead of html when handling ajax POST requests. This is a genuine problem for my developed debugging logic from the previous version, as I've counted on laravel returning a rendered HTML page of the error as the `.responseText` of the response, so I could easily display the whole content in a new window and see it clearly (for debugging purposes). What happens now is basically the following:

- `.$ajax()` POST request is being sent to the server;
- some serverside php error occurs in the function handling the response (say, unknown variable for example)
- so the ajax `error` function of the request receives its first argument (`xhr`), which is as of right now a JSON array with the following structure:
  [image]
- now I'd like to display that message in a new window, but with the rendered HTML layout that Laravel usually provides and I really like

I really wouldn't want to have to begin building the html look all by my own when I already know, that Laravel could render it for me. The problem is that I couldn't find recent documentations on the topic, nor a proper way to return a rendered html content as a response. So my question is, could anyone advise me as of what is the best alternative of rendering the html content? Which method is the best way of receiving what I want and is there still any particular such method? Thansk in advance!

**Edit**
Here's my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: '/updateModel',
    data: dataObject,
    success: success
});
```

Where `dataObject` is really only the contained data for the request. What I've got in my initial `.js` file though is the following:

```
$(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
                showGlobalLoader(true); //shows the loader
            })
            .ajaxStop(function() {
                showGlobalLoader(false); //hides the loader
            })
            .ajaxError(ajaxErrorGlobalFunction); //displays the new window - that's the function in question
        });
```

And then that's the `ajaxErrorGlobalFunction` function

```
function ajaxErrorGlobalFunction(xhr, status, error) {
    if (xhr.responseText) {
        //console.log(xhr.responseText);
        openErrorWindow(xhr.responseJSON);
    }
}


function openErrorWindow(json = "")
{
    var w = window.open('', '_blank', 'scrollbars=no,status=no,titlebar=no');
    $(w.document.body).html(json.message + "\n in file " + json.file + "\n on line " + json.line);
    w.resizeTo(1000, 1000);
    w.moveTo(0, 0);
    w.focus();
}
```

As you can see, I used to just render the `xhr.responseText` as the html content of the window, but now I got forced to work it around by extracting the most important information from the json. I'd really like to have the good old html content back as a response of the request. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us your ajax post request? Normally when you don't want a json, Laravel doesn't return a json.

Comment: @ChinLeung I've edited my post with all the code I could come up with that's related to the topic. If I've forgotten something, excuse me! I'll add it if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the exceptions handler (**Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php**:**185**):

```
return $request->expectsJson()
    ? $this->prepareJsonResponse($request, $e)
    : $this->prepareResponse($request, $e);
```

If the request wants a json as response, it will convert it to json, otherwise it will render it as it used to.

Add a `dataType` to your Ajax request that isn't json and this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: '/updateModel',
    data: dataObject,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: success
});
```

---

### Update

If you want to always display the exceptions as HTML, you can update the **render function** of the exception handler (**app/Exceptions/Handler.php**) by copying the parent's render function and remove the `expectsJson` ternary:

```
if (method_exists($e, 'render') && $response = $e->render($request)) {
    return Router::toResponse($request, $response);
} elseif ($e instanceof Responsable) {
    return $e->toResponse($request);
}

$e = $this->prepareException($e);

if ($e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
    return $e->getResponse();
} elseif ($e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
    return $this->unauthenticated($request, $e);
} elseif ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
    return $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($e, $request);
}

return $this->prepareResponse($request, $e);
```

Comment: Okay, that's something new to me! I understand, but the problem is that I really need and return a json response if everything is okay, but if there are any errors, I'd like to handle the rendered html content in the `error` function of my ajax request. Would that be possible?

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed!